# Refresh table after post in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-component

After a post I would like to reload my table to be able to display the data after the post. Now the question arises how to get my "DataProvider" to render again?

I would do this as a function call in "FormOPCConnect". But I don't know how to start. I already tried to use the "props" of the "DataProvider", but I can't figure out how to render the new table.

Enclosed my source code.

TableOPCConnections.js

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import key from "weak-key";
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table'

const OPCVarTable = ({ data }) =>
  !data.length ? (
    <p>Nothing to show</p>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <h2 className="subtitle">
        Showing <strong>{data.length}</strong> OPC Variables
      </h2>
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {Object.entries(data[0]).map(el => <th key={key(el)}>{el[0]}</th>)}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map(el => (
            <tr key={el.id}>
              {Object.entries(el).map(el => <td key={key(el)}>{el[1]}</td>)}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
OPCVarTable.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default OPCVarTable;
```

DataProvider.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class DataProvider extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    endpoint: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    render: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };
  state = {
      data: [],
      loaded: false,
      placeholder: "Loading..."
    };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.props.endpoint)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          return this.setState({ placeholder: "Something went wrong" });
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => this.setState({ data: data, loaded: true }));
  }
  render() {
    const { data, loaded, placeholder } = this.state;
    return loaded ? this.props.render(data) : <p>{placeholder}</p>;
  }
}
export default DataProvider;
```

FormOPCConnect.js 
(Here I'd like to refresh the state of the DataProvider)

After the fetch method I would like to render the table again as long as the post to the database was successful.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import DataProvider from "./DataProvider";

import csrftoken from './csrftoken';

class FormOPCConnect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      validated: false
    };
  }
  static propTypes = {
    endpoint: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };
  state = {
    ip_address: "",
    port: "",
    namespace_name: "",
    root_name: "",
    owner: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    const { ip_address, port, namespace_name, root_name, owner } = this.state;
    const opcConn= { ip_address, port, namespace_name, root_name, owner };
    const conf = {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify(opcConn),
      headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json", "X-CSRFTOKEN": csrftoken })
    }

    fetch(this.props.endpoint, conf).then(response => console.log(response));

    //>>
    //if response is valid -> refresh the Dataprovider and the table...
    //<<

    this.setState({ validated: this.state.validated = true })

  };
```

App.js

```
const App = () => (
<React.Fragment>
<Container>
<Row>
 <Col> <NavBarTop fixed="top" /> </Col>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Col>  <DataProvider endpoint="opcconnection/"
                render={data => <OPCVarTable data={data} />} /></Col>
    <Col><FormOPCConnect endpoint="opcconnection/" /></Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
  </React.Fragment>
);

const wrapper = document.getElementById("app");

wrapper ? ReactDOM.render(<App />, wrapper) : null;
```

I'm new to React, so please forgive my mistakes. :D

Finally it looks like this.
[OPCConnection_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiEIF.png)

Comment: 1st .that is too much code to check can you just provide only the necessary code 
and 2nd i never done it but as much as i know 
You need to update your state every time when you dont a post request . and it will update ur table automatically

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I removed the unnecessary parts, thank you. I think the rest has to stay that way, because otherwise you can't see the connections? Yes, I tried that already.  But when I call the states of the DataProvider, how does it happen that rendering is triggered again?

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently contains **2** problems that need to be fixed in order to update your table when you post data.

---

**1)** 
Your `DataProvider` does actually rerender on `props` change. The problem here is that your logic to fetch your `data` is in `componentDidMount`. `componentDidMount` only triggers the first time the component mounts and doesn't trigger on rerender.

If you want your data to fetch everytime the component rerenders you could place your fetch functionality in your `render` method of `DataProvider`.

To rerender a component all you have to do is update its `props` or it's `state`.

---

**2)** You want your `DataProvider` to update when your `FormOPCConnect` has finished some logic.

The thing with React is. You can only pass variables from `parents` to `children`. You can't directly communicate from `sibling` to `sibling` or from `child` to `parent`.

In your `App` your `DataProvider` is a siblign of `FormOPCConnect`, they are next to eachother.

```
<App> // App can communicate with every component inside it.
   <DataProvider /> // This component can't communicate with the component next to it.
   <FormOPCConnect />
</App>
```

The easiest thing to do here would be to either render `DataProvider` inside `FormOPCConnect` and update `DataProvider`'s props directly.

Or if that is not possible, keep a state in `App` which checks if your logic in `FormOPCConnect` has finished.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { boolean: false }; //state is remembered when a component updates.
  }

  flipBoolean() { //this function updates the state and rerenders App when called.
    this.setState(
      boolean: boolean!
    );
  };

  render {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <DataProvider />
        <FormOPCConnect flipBoolean={this.flipBoolean} />
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Pass a function to `FormOPCConnect` which updates the state of `App`. When you want your `DataProvider` to rerender you simply call that `flipBoolean` function in `FormOPCConnect`. This will update the `state` in `App`. Which will trigger `App` to rerender. Which will in it's turn rerender it's children `DataProvider and`FormOPCConnect`.

(This variable doesn't need to be a boolean, you can do here whatever you want. This boolean is just an example).

Comment: The solution would then be to `fetch` the data into a general function in the `DataProvider`? And then to call it after the post if necessary?

Comment: Either that, or `fetch` it directly in your render method of `DataProvider` instead of in your `componentDidMount`

Comment: Ok I got it, but how do I call the render function of the `DataProvider` again in the `FormOPCConnect` class?

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide some more explanation about how communication between react components works

Comment: Thank you, Luze, for the answer. I have implemented this as described in solution 2. However, it is not my desired result. As a `DataProvider` I understand a module or class that gets me the corresponding data about the given endpoint. And I would like to be able to trigger this from anywhere. So the `DataProvider` is always reusable. Which it is no longer, as soon as I include it in the `FormOPCConnect`, as in this example.
In the second solution in solution 2, I force all children to render themselves again, which again is not my desired result, because this involves rendering the form too.